# DNS settings updated in whois, but site still looking at old servers

Tags: domain-name-system, website

I have migrated a site from a external Linux server to a new IIS server. DNS settings have been updated and are showing correctly in whois, squish.net, traceroute. However, when I type in the domain, I am still looking at the old site on desktop. Mobile version via cell (not LAN) is pointing to new site. It's been 48 hours.

Ping should be going to either 68.71.132.98/68.71.13299 or 72.18.129.7/72.18.137.218.

How can I clear that old DNS caching that seems to be stuck? Or another question, is: What do you see?
The old site is has HTML files.
The new site (temporary address) can be viewed correctly at http://aikenenviroscape.com.wehostwebsites.com and is .CFM (coldfusion). Large photo on home page.

Answer (score 2):

If you can see it correctly via the cell, then your local DNS is stale (you can also go to an external location like Starbucks and check from there to see this).  From where I am (NY, using Verizon as my provider), I see .cfm files.

Clearing the local DNS depends on how your local network is set up.  Possibly, there's something on the router, or on the Domain Server, etc.  It's also possible your workstations have stale DNS information; clearing that depends on your setup.

Update:

It looks like the TTL is 2 days.  It may take 48 hours to fully clear, where you can't flush the DNS cache.  You probably should have shortened the TTL before the move (i.e., 2 days is really, really long; TTLs are more commonly under a day).  You get the benefit of making rollback easier, if nothing else.

Comment: Thanks, at least it is beginning to be updated. I have no control over setting the TTL in this case :|, but I didn't realize it was set to 2 days (geesh).

Comment: I checked on my end, and the TTL for my registrar is 1 hour, so a 2 day TTL may be coming from the the 'sending' registrar or the host, neither of which I can update.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what the TTL for the DNS record is. If (for example) it's set to 1 week then 48 hours won't be long enough for a recursive resolver to flush it from its cache.

If you control a local resolver, I'd suggest flushing its cache. If you don't, then check out the TTL for the domain name. That will tell you roughly how long you need to wait for the update to propagate.